# How can I get the parse tree for arithmetic operations in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, parsing, arithmetic-expressions, parse-tree

How do I obtain a list of function calls for this following simple arithmetic operations?  How can I get the parse tree?

```
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> (2+3)*5 % 7
4
```

Additionally, where in the Python [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython) is the grammar for parsing arithmetic expressions?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ast` module to get the abstract syntax tree. The `astpretty` [module](https://github.com/asottile/astpretty) makes it, well, prettier to visualize:

```
>>> astpretty.pprint(ast.parse('(2+3)*5 % 7'))
Module(
    body=[
        Expr(
            lineno=1,
            col_offset=0,
            value=BinOp(
                lineno=1,
                col_offset=8,
                left=BinOp(
                    lineno=1,
                    col_offset=0,
                    left=BinOp(
                        lineno=1,
                        col_offset=1,
                        left=Num(lineno=1, col_offset=1, n=2),
                        op=Add(),
                        right=Num(lineno=1, col_offset=3, n=3),
                    ),
                    op=Mult(),
                    right=Num(lineno=1, col_offset=6, n=5),
                ),
                op=Mod(),
                right=Num(lineno=1, col_offset=10, n=7),
            ),
        ),
    ],
)
```

The full grammar for 2.7 is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/grammar.html).